# Sorting a list whose items are strings of letters then number in C++

Tags: c++, string, list, sorting

I have a list of items called "cat", "mouse" and "bird" then followed by a number (ranging from 1 to math.inf) that I want to sort.

For now I have coded this:
`ui->creature_list->sortItems();`
(I am working in C++ with Qt) But this sorts by string, so I have something for example like:
Mylist:
cat 1
cat 10
cat 2
cat 3
cat 4
cat 5
cat 6
cat 7
cat 8
cat 9
Here the 10 goes after the "cat 1" as it's not a number but a string. How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Split the string into two fields.  String compare first field, if equal convert 2nd field to a number and do an int compare.

Comment: If the number is used for more than just sorting, you might consider to store as a struct/tuple/pair of string and number. With `std::pair<std::string,int>` it would be sorted correctly without any extra code (except for the split). If it is mostly used for printing out, then just split it while sorting.

Comment: Please find my updated answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sorting method that you need is called “natural sorting”. You may read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order) here about it.

You will find thus many answers here on SO already. The problem is that the shown solutions are rather complicated and do not explain that much.

Additionally, your solution could be solved by splitting the string in 2 parts and then comparing the number separately. But, in essence, this is, exactly, what I am doing in the below example.

Let us analyze the issue a little deeper. First, we start with the old “strcmp” algorithm.

“strcmp” compares 2 strings character by character. And the comparison is done by subtracting the characters. If characters are equal, then the result of the subtraction is 0. If one is smaller, e.g., “A” is smaller than “B”, then the result will be negative. Otherwise, positive.

If you look at the definition of the old “strcmp” function [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp), then you will see, that it exactly behaves as mentioned above.

So, how to approach the problems with numbers and natural sorting?

The solution is, to treat a number, consisting of one or many digits, as one entity. Then we compare these entities (the numbers formed by the digits) and continue to compare more characters after the digits (number).

Example: “cat 10 gray” and “cat 10 black”:

1. Compare 'C' with 'C', equal, continue
2. Compare 'a' with 'a', equal, continue
3. Compare 't' with 't', equal, continue
4. Compare ' ' with ' ', equal, continue
5. Find a digit. Consume all digits and build a number, compare the numbers, they are equal, so continue
6. Set the next character to evaluate to one after the number
7. Compare ' ' with ' ', equal, continue
8. Compare 'g' with 'b', equal, continue. 'g' -'b' is positive, so “cat 10 gray” is greater than “cat 10 black”. The result is available. No need to continue. Stop the function and return the result.

Now, an example with 2 different numbers. Example: “cat 2 gray” and “cat 10 gray”:

1. Compare 'C' with 'C', equal, continue
2. Compare 'a' with 'a', equal, continue
3. Compare 't' with 't', equal, continue
4. Compare ' ' with ' ', equal, continue
5. Find a digit. Consume all the digits and build a number, compare the numbers, one is 2 and the other is 10. Subtract 2-10. The result is negative. So, 2 is smaller than 10, and, with that, “cat 2 gray” is smaller than “cat 10 gray”.

If you make a “normal” comparison, then the result is opposite.

Let us come to the implementation. It is not that complicated.

```
// Needed for the comparison function
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

// Needed for the test code and output
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iomanip>

// Natural sort function. Limited to signed char strings
int naturalSort(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) {

    // We want to iterate over both strings
    const char* i1 = s1.data(); // Get a pointer to the beginning of string 1
    const char* i2 = s2.data(); // Get a pointer to the beginning of string 2

    // Result of comparison. 0 means equal, positive means s1>s2, negative means s1<s2
    int result = 0;
    // As long as both characters/numbers are equal and there are still characters in the string
    do {
        // If we found a digit at the same position in both strings
        if (std::isdigit(*i1) and std::isdigit(*i2)) {

            std::size_t pos1{}, pos2{}; // This will later indicate how many digits we read
            // Convert the strings to numbers and compare them
            result = std::stoi(i1, &pos1) - std::stoi(i2, &pos2);
            // Set pointers to the position after the number
            i1 += pos1; i2 += pos2;
        }
        else {
            // Normal character
            result = (*i1 - *i2);
            ++i1; ++i2;
        }
    } while ((result == 0) and (*i1 != 0 or *i2 != 0));
    // Let's limit the output to -1, 0 ,1
    return std::clamp(result, -1, 1);
}
// Driver / test code
int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> test{
        {"",""},
        {"ABC",""},
        {"","ABC"},
        {"ABC","ABD"},
        {"ABC","ABC"},
        {"ABD","ABC"},
        {"ABC","ABCD"},
        {"ABCD","ABC"},
        {"ABC","ABCD  "},
        {"ABCD","ABC  "},
        {"1",""},
        {"","1"},
        {"1","10"},
        {"10","1"},
        {" 1","1"},
        {"1"," 1"},
        {"a1","aa1"},
        {"aa1","a1"},
        {"A10B","A10C"},
        {"A10B","A11B"},
        {"A11B","A10B"},
        {"A1BC","A10BC"},
        {"A10BC","A1BC"},
        {"CAT 1","CAT 10"},
        {"CAT 10","CAT 1"},
        {"CAT1","CAT10"},
        {"CAT10","CAT1"},
        {"CAT10","CAT10"},
        {"AXYZ1BC","AXYZ10BC"},
        {"AXYZ10BC","AXYZ1BC"},
        {"AXYZ1000BCDEF","AXYZ1001BCDEF"},
        {"AXYZ1001BCDEF","AXYZ1000BCDEF"},
        {"AXYZ1000BCDEFGH","AXYZ1001BCDEF"},
        {"AXYZ1001BCDEFGH","AXYZ1000BCDEF"},
    };
    for (const auto& [s1, s2] : test)
        std::cout << std::right << std::setw(15) << s1 << " <comp> " << std::left << std::setw(15) << s2 << "  -> " << naturalSort(s1, s2) << '\n';
}
```

OK, I hope that this is understandable.

Let us build a functor for that and use it with `std::sort` for sorting a `std::vector` "naturally".

```
// Needed for the comparison function
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

// Needed for the test code and output
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iomanip>

// FUNCTOR for Natural sort function. Limited to signed char strings
struct NaturalSort {

    bool operator ()(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) {

        // We want to iterate over both strings
        const char* i1 = s1.data(); // Get a pointer to the beginning of string 1
        const char* i2 = s2.data(); // Get a pointer to the beginning of string 2

        // Result of comparison. 0 means equal, positive means s1>s2, negative means s1<s2
        int result = 0;
        // As long as both characters/numbers are equal and there are still characters in the string
        do {
            // If we found a digit at the same position in both strings
            if (std::isdigit(*i1) and std::isdigit(*i2)) {

                std::size_t pos1{}, pos2{}; // This will later indicate how many digits we read
                // Convert the strings to numbers and compare them
                result = std::stoi(i1, &pos1) - std::stoi(i2, &pos2);
                // Set pointers to the position after the number
                i1 += pos1; i2 += pos2;
            }
            else {
                // Normal character
                result = (*i1 - *i2);
                ++i1; ++i2;
            }
        } while ((result == 0) and (*i1 != 0 or *i2 != 0));
        // Let's limit the output to -1, 0 ,1
        return result < 0;
    }
};
// Driver / test code
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> test{ "Cat 1", "Cat 2", "Cat 10", "Cat 20", "Cat" };

    std::cout << "\nNormal sort:\n\n";
    std::sort(test.begin(), test.end());
    for (const std::string& s : test)  std::cout << s << '\n';

    std::cout << "\n\nNatural sort:\n\n";
    std::sort(test.begin(), test.end(), NaturalSort());
    for (const std::string& s: test)  std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Program output:

[image]